# Sharepoint application page only loads one Jquery script link

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have edited a homepage for my site. I added links to my jquery files from my stylelibrary locates on the same site. below is my placeholder head code.

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleLibrary/CSS/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="StyleLibrary/JS/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="StyleLibrary/JS/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#hometab").tabs();
});
    </script>
   </asp:Content>
```

for some reason I see in fiddler that only the css file in jquery.min.js is loaded why doesn't it load jquery custom.. This is really weird and I don't see why It would load the others and not this specific one. I am trying to create a tab ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="StyleLibrary/JS/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**:
The `script` Tag omission must have a start tag and end tag.
[Script | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script)
[Why dont self closing script tags work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: You are awesome please explain to me why did that make a difference. I swear SharePoint is frustrating. Now my dataview webparts arent in the tabs.

Comment: As soon as it lets me set you as the answer I will give credit

Comment: Can you help me get the webpart zones to show within the tabs

Comment: I figured out the tab divs was using class instead of id's I greatly appreciate your help. Have a Great Day :)

Comment: +1 for the SO link.